# Implementing a container for both const and mutable types in C++

Tags: c++, oop, constants

Let's say we have a `class X` that holds a pointer to an object of `class Y`. `X` never changes `Y` in any way, but other objects which might want to change `Y` can ask `X` for a pointer to `Y`. We want `class X` to be able to hold both `const` and variable objects. If we write something like this:

```cpp
class Y;

class X {
public:
  const Y* getY();
private:
  const Y* y;
};
```

then we could never alter `Y` when getting it from `X`, even when the original "`Y` object" is not `const`.

An example where this would be useful is a linked list that holds both `const` and variable objects.

How would one go about implementing this?

Comment: Since you know the `Y` instance is mutable (guaranteed by forces above your head) return a non-`const` `Y *` and `const_cast` away the `const` in the getter. C++ always gives you the opportunity to do something stupid when there's a chance that it might not be stupid under controlled circumstances. 's why we still have widely reviled stuff like `goto`.

Comment: But remember that you have to be absolutely sure the sucker's mutable, so storing mutable and non-mutable data in the same container... That's stupid. But you could be able to get around it safely with the right abstraction.

Comment: So if I wanted class X to be able to hold both mutable and const objects, that would not be very smart then?

Comment: @user4581301 • Our `goto` has been castrated, since you can't do `void foo() { goto yonder; } void bar() { yonder: cout << "We're here!\n"; }`  We've got **structured** goto, that's been tamed, constrained, and detained, rather than proper *yeehaw* goto that can rampage hither-and-yon.  *Assembly language programming, for the win!*

Comment: @m_ognjen *So if I wanted class X to be able to hold both mutable and const objects...* If you have no way to guarantee that the `Y` is mutable, casting away `const` is not a good solution. But if you have a wrapper around it that can tell you if it's mutable or not  you have the ability to say "Oh hell no!" if someone asks for a non-`const` pointer. Saying "No" may or may not be viable in your use case, but perhaps you can move the abstraction elsewhere.

Comment: The problem you're walking into is kind of like having a container of pointers that could be automatically or dynamically allocated and being responsible for deleting the pointed-at objects. Toss the right kind of smart pointer between your code and the objects of unknown source, delegate the deletion to the smart pointer, and the problem goes away.

Comment: It might be an XY problem. I presume you want to lookup and sometimes modify it. My suggestion: keep a const container having all mutable and immutable items for lookup, and keep another one only for mutable items. (The latter one might be a map which is easier to lookup from the const container). Or change your declaration of `X` to make it return `nullptr` if it holds a const Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about the analogous situation of `std::unique_ptr`: one that holds a pointer to a *mutable* `Y` is `std::unique_ptr<Y>`, while one that holds a pointer to a `const` `Y` is `std::unique_ptr<const Y>`.

`X` can similarly be made into a template:

```
class Y;

template <class T>
class X {
public:
    T* getY();
private:
    T* p;
};
```

Here, `X<Y>` can hold a `Y*`, and `X<const Y>` can hold a `const Y*`. You may also want to make `X<Y>` implicitly convertible to `X<const Y>` by providing an appropriate constructor, so that any function that has a parameter of type `X<const Y>` can be called with an argument of type `X<Y>`:

```
template <class T>
class X {
public:
    X(const X& other) = default;

    X(const X<std::remove_const_t<T>>& other)
    requires (!std::is_const_v<T>)
    : p(other.getY()) {}

    T* getY() const;
private:
    T* p;
};
```

If you want to hide the templatedness from the users, you can do so like this:

```
namespace detail {
template <class T>
class X_impl {
public:
    X_impl(const X_impl& other) = default;

    X_impl(const X_impl<std::remove_const_t<T>>& other)
    requires (!std::is_const_v<T>)
    : p(other.getY()) {}

    T* getY() const;
private:
    T* p;
};
}  // namespace detail

using X = X_impl<Y>;
using CX = X_impl<const Y>;
```

Comment: I knew about templates, but I wondered if there was a simpler solution, but the part about hiding the template is very interesting. Is that a common design pattern?

Comment: @m_ognjen I don't think anything I wrote here is particularly uncommon. I don't know if it's a design pattern with a well-known name, though.